# How to run owl carousel after http call with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, owl-carousel

Hi I have one that throws owl carousel directive , but I have a factory that makes a call to the server getting the data I need to draw the container carousel owl , how do I get after the call **$http** is finished I draw the carousel owl ? My code is as follows

**Directive**

```
    app.directive('wrapOwlcarousel',['$timeout',function ($timeout) {  
    return {  
        restrict: 'E',  
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 

                 $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                    var options = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));  
                    $(element).owlCarousel(options);
                    alert('carouel')
                });
        }  
    };  
]});
```

Controller

```
 app.controller('HomeController',[
    '$scope','$location','$timeout','Storage',function($scope,$location,$timeout,Storage){

        $timeout(function(){

            angular.element('#footer').css({
                'bottom' : '0'
            })

        },100);

        $scope.getClass = function(path) 
        { 
            if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path){
                    if (path == "/" && $location.path() == "/") { return "active"; }
                    else if (path == "/") {  return ""; }

                    return "active" 

            } else { return "" } 
        }

        var items = Storage.has('posts');

        if(items){
            $scope.eventos = Storage.get('posts');
        }else{
            alert('no info')
        }


    }
]);
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('EventFunctions',['$http','appSettings',function($http,appSettings){
    return {
        getAllPosts : function(){

            return $http.get(appSettings._url).then(function(result) {
               return result.data;
           });

        }
    }

}]);
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: i think there is a lead here:http://javascriipt.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-reinitialize-owl-carousel-after.html

Comment: but this is with angular, something need to be different, but thanks for toy reply :)

Comment: Please be sure to read the descriptions of the tags you put on your questions. This is not a question about the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]), but about the OWL Carousel ([tag:owl-carousel]).  The right tags get people that know what you're asking about looking at your question, whereas with the wrong tags, they won't see the question at all.

Comment: don't worry i will do my best ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer!

my directive have an syntax error, this is my new directive file

```
app.directive('wrapOwlcarousel',['$timeout',function ($timeout) {  
    return {  
        restrict: 'E',  
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 

                 $timeout(function () {
                    var options = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));  
                    $(element).owlCarousel(options);
                });


        }  
    };  
}]);
```